# Interesting behavior comparing integer with array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

In PHP I had to compare if an integer variable was less than a value of an array, but I had an error in the code and I found by chance an unexpected behavior.

I was comparing the integer with the array itself and it was returning true. Do you know why?

I've been searching about this in StackOverflow and php.net [(PHP types comparisons)](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and I didn't found a specific answer.

Here you have a little code to test this.

```
<?php

$myArray = array();
$myInt = 1;

if($myInt < $myArray){
    echo "Int less than array\n";
}

if($myInt == $myArray){
    echo "Int equal to array\n";
}

if($myInt > $myArray){
    echo "Int greater than array\n";
}
```

I've tried different values for `$myInt` and different contents for `$myArray` and it always prints this:

```
Int less than array
```

Comment: Casting an empty array to `int` results in `0`.

Comment: @JonStirling That's what I would have thought as well, but then the last condition should match and not the first...

Comment: @jeroen Ah. Chuck Norris saves the day again :P

Comment: @JonStirling Yep :-)

Comment: Can I ask why You need to do such comparison?  What You want to achieve with this?

Comment: @RafalKozlowski Actually I don't need it. As I said in the question, I found this by mistake, and was just wondering why is it giving true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing an array to anything else result in array is always greater :

[see php doc - section Comparison with Various Types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)