# How is this (erroneous) comparison done by PHP?

Tags: php

Assume the following code, which tries to determine whether the array has more than 3 elements. Note, that I am aware that this is done normally using `count($array)` and comparing the integers, but I got curious as to why

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
var_dump($array > 3);
```

returns `true`, which it, actually, does independently of the value of the right comparison operand in the `var_dump`, so `$array > 3` is no different than `$array > 3000`.

My question lies in what sort of typecasting happens internally in PHP when an array is compared to an integer in this *entirely inappropriate* manner, or whether there is a case where this manner is indeed appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interesting behavior comparing integer with array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287235/interesting-behavior-comparing-integer-with-array-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), it says:

> `array    anything    array is always greater`
>
> [image: array comparison]

So when you compare anything with array, then array is greater. I am now going to check array vs. object.

Comment: That's even more interesting now. `(int)$array` has the value of `1` for me, but the expression still evaluates to true.